# Why aren't my node.js heroku task console.log statements displayed in the heroku log?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I've got a super simple node.js task set up in heroku per [this blog](http://www.spacjer.com/blog/2014/02/10/defining-node-dot-js-task-for-heroku-scheduler/).  Everything seems to be working, but my console.log statement doesn't display in the console when I use `heroku logs --tail`.

My task looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var firebase = require('firebase')
console.log('I have loaded firebase');
```

I know it's running because I didn't have the firebase npm package in the pacakages.json and got the expected error.  Once that was resolved, everything seems to run fine, but I don't get any output from my console.log line.  =[

I'm executed the task with `heroku run reconcileTasks` and get the following output in the log tail:

```
2016-02-25T21:47:00.483677+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `reconcileTasks` by somecoolfella@geemail.com
2016-02-25T21:47:01.648730+00:00 heroku[run.2829]: Awaiting client
2016-02-25T21:47:01.687472+00:00 heroku[run.2829]: Starting process with command `reconcileTasks`
2016-02-25T21:47:01.945501+00:00 heroku[run.2829]: State changed from starting to up
2016-02-25T21:47:03.964158+00:00 heroku[run.2829]: Process exited with status 0
2016-02-25T21:47:03.991854+00:00 heroku[run.2829]: State changed from up to complete
```

Answer (score 1):

After having scheduled the task to run over night, I discovered the logs show the message I was expecting.  Apparently, the console.log goes to the context in which the user is going to see it.  When I run it manually via the `heroku run` command, it shows up in the console in which I'm working, but when the heroku scheduler runs it, it shows up in the logs.  That's some pretty cool magic.  =]

```
2016-02-26T05:30:16.396497+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `reconcileTasks` by scheduler@addons.heroku.com
2016-02-26T05:30:17.623505+00:00 heroku[scheduler.7098]: Starting process with command `reconcileTasks`
2016-02-26T05:30:18.316360+00:00 heroku[scheduler.7098]: State changed from starting to up
2016-02-26T05:30:19.866568+00:00 app[scheduler.7098]: I have loaded firebase
2016-02-26T05:30:20.819687+00:00 heroku[scheduler.7098]: State changed from up to complete
2016-02-26T05:30:20.805612+00:00 heroku[scheduler.7098]: Process exited with status 0
```